# How to block specific number on twilio

Tags: twilio

SO I have a website that is getting some calls and I'm forwarding those calls to my client through Twilio.

I've created a call forwarding workflow in twilio and then connected that workflow to a specific number. Now I'm getting some junk calls to & i want to block those specific number is there any easy way to do that?

here's a screenshot of the workflow.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a SPLIT block:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on

Split is an additional block for "if match" logic, your split block can focus on the incoming caller ID number where "if incoming number = XXX take route A - ELSE - for everyone else, take route B" you would insert this block before the forward_call block handler and update the logic regularly with the numbers you wish to drop in route A.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Studio is great, but in your case this code sample might be even better as it already does what you are looking for :)
https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/block-spam-calls